# Django Admin show Image immediately after upload

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

maybe this issue is answered elsewhere, but I have no luck of finding it.
Here is my issue:
I have a Django admin site that has an ImageField to upload image look like this

[image]

In order to show the uploaded image, I will have to click on *Save/ Save and add another/ Save and continue editing*.

What I really want is show preview of the picture immediately after I upload it.

Is there anyway to trigger it via ImageField override or somehow?

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because you haven't actually uploaded the image yet. When you "choose file" you've basically just told the browser which file you want to upload, but it doesn't get uploaded until you submit the form.

Comment: I see, however, do you think there is any workaround to archive my purpose?

Comment: No, because the browser won't let you access images from your local filesystem.  They have to be uploaded before you can show them.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sorl.thumbnail, but you can easily adapt it into django.
Below is Django model class

```
Class ImageModel(admin.Models):
...
    myfield = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to='project/%Y', null=True, blank=True)
...
@property
def image_tag(self):
    im = get_thumbnail(self.myfield.file, 'x300', crop='center', quality=99)
    return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="%s" height="%s" />' % (im.url, im.width, im.height))
```